# Javascript replace SEVERAL broken images until you find a good one

Tags: javascript, image, onerror

I have seen code for replacing a broken image with javascript using onerror, but I have a situation where I'm not sure what image is going to be available for a replacement, so I need to do multiple checks and I'm not sure how... Here's an example of what I need...

`<img src="http://www.example.com/myimage1.png">`

If that image isn't available, I need to check a different location for an image.  that location will be...

`<img src="http://www.example.com/myimage2.png">`

If that image isn't available, I need to check,

`<img src="http://www.example.com/myimage3.png">`

and finally, if that image isn't available, I use my default image that I know is always available

`<img src="http://www.example.com/default.png">`

javascript only please, no jquery

Comment: I do know how to replace ONE broken image, but not sure how to do it if the replacement is also broken, and keep checking a few images until I find one that works.